# How to make a Beowulf Cluster with Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: beowulf

I have a few PCs just laying around and want to put them to work. While in my research, i came across Parallel computing and a few forms of it. The one that appealed to me was the Beowulf Cluster. However, all tutorials i found were outdated since Ubuntu 8.04. I wish to make a Beowulf Cluster with Ubuntu 12.10. . . or at least something similar to a Beowulf Cluster. Can anyone Help?.

Comment: What kind of calculations do you want to do with all your computers?

Comment: i just want a my computer to be able to run the GUI from one computer with the processing of the two computers

Comment: And what programs do you want to run? As far as I know, the program has to support it. You cannot just blindly combine the processing power, as far as I know it.

Comment: just google chrome, minecraft, libreoffice, and spotify